# How to iterate over a specific column of a spreadsheet with a loop and save the resultant value in next column

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-sheets

[image: Image or sample spread sheet]

as shown in image. I want to pick a google search url using webdriver, launch this url in google.com, pick the result count and insert it in next column in front of the url. Im connecting, opening and launching the first url correctly but i want to run all urls and put values in column of spread sheet in a single go in one loop. Given is the code reading first url, please help

```
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = 
ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)


sheet = client.open("Popular Searches - Warmup").sheet1  

ellData=str(sheet.cell(1,2))
print cellData
firstUrl = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", cellData).group("url")
print "\nUrl is : " + firstUrl

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(firstUrl)
```

Comment: You might be better of using the API for Google Sheets: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/

Comment: already using bro that's why im able to connect to google spreadsheet